# Encryption with Conceal API

Tags: android, encryption, javadoc

Is it possible to encrypt small amount of data, like `byte arrays`, with Conceal API? I'm interested in its performance, but I don't need to encrypt files. 
Does it have `javadoc` documentation? Sample of code would be very appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The official Conceal [Documentation](https://github.com/facebook/conceal) is the facebook conceal github page, you can find some usage examples.

Basically conceal helps you encrypt streams of information so I think it is possible to encrypt any OutputStream you choose using Conceal.